# Devise gem is adding Responders gem. How to remove it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

This is my gemfile info for Devise : gem 'devise', branch: 'lm-rails-4-2'

I am using Rails 4.2.0 and after bundling, whenever I try to scaffold something, I am getting something like this :

```
 respond_to :html

  def index
    @assets = Asset.all
    respond_with(@assets)
  end
```

This is because of the responders gem. How do I remove it?

Using Ruby 2.1.2

Comment: You cannot if devise depends on it. An by the way if you use `respond_to` and `respond_with` in Rails 4.2 you must add responders gem. More here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#respond-with-class-level-respond-to

Comment: But when I was using the earlier versions of Devise it was not using it.. Also, I dont think that I need to add the responders gem as Devise already added it for me.

Comment: I posted a link into my earlier comment, read what's there and you will understand why. In Rails 4.2 respond_with was moved into responders gem, devise uses respond_with, so, responders gem is a dependency for devise now. That's OK.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get rid of it and use devise at the same time, then you need to do this:

- fork devise
- remove the dependency and all references to responders from the codebase
- link your fork in your projects gemfile with `github: "yourname/devise"`

i'd really advise against doing this.